# Bidirectionnal relation in form

Tags: symfony, doctrine

i'm having difficulties to save a form that contains a collection from a OneToMany bidirectionnal relation.

I got the following error :

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO fieldsgroup (title, colloque_id) VALUES (?, ?)' with params ["groupe 1", null]:
```

Here are the queries that the profiler gives me :
    START TRANSACTION;

```
INSERT INTO colloque (title)
VALUES
  ('titre du colloque');

INSERT INTO fieldsgroup (title, colloque_id)
VALUES
  ('titre de mon groupe de champs', null)

ROLLBACK
```

My controller :

```
public function createColloqueAction()
{

  $colloque = new Colloque();   
  $form = $this->createForm(new ColloqueType, $colloque);   

  $request = $this->get('request');   
  if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST'){   
    $form->bind($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {

      $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('notice', 'Colloque correctement enregistré');

      $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
      $em->persist($colloque);
      $em->flush();

      return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('ptolemee_admin_homepage'));
    }   

  }       

  return $this->render('PtolemeeAdminBundle:Admin:createColloque.html.twig',array(
    'form'    =>   $form->createView()                                         
  ));
}
```

My "Colloque" entity :

```
class Colloque
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Ptolemee\ColloqueBundle\Entity\FieldsGroup", mappedBy="colloque", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $fieldsGroups; 

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->fieldsGroups = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add fieldsGroups
     *
     * @param \Ptolemee\ColloqueBundle\Entity\FieldsGroup $fieldsGroups
     * @return Colloque
     */
    public function addFieldsGroup(\Ptolemee\ColloqueBundle\Entity\FieldsGroup $fieldsGroups)
    {
        $this->fieldsGroups[] = $fieldsGroups;
        $fieldsGroups->setColloque($this);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove fieldsGroups
     *
     * @param \Ptolemee\ColloqueBundle\Entity\FieldsGroup $fieldsGroups
     */
    public function removeFieldsGroup(\Ptolemee\ColloqueBundle\Entity\FieldsGroup $fieldsGroups)
    {
        $this->fieldsGroups->removeElement($fieldsGroups);
    }

    /**
     * Get fieldsGroups
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getFieldsGroups()
    {
        return $this->fieldsGroups;
    }
}
```

Its form, ColloqueType :

```
class ColloqueType extends AbstractType
{
        /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title',              'text')
            ->add('date',               'datetime')
            ->add('successMessage',     'textarea')
            ->add('fieldsGroups',       'collection',   array(  'type'        =>      new FieldsGroupType(),
                                                                'allow_add'   =>      true,
                                                                'allow_delete'   =>   true))
        ;
    }
}
```

My class FieldsGroup

```
class FieldsGroup
{

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**                                                                                  
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Ptolemee\ColloqueBundle\Entity\Colloque", inversedBy="fieldsGroups")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $colloque;

    /**
     * Set colloque
     *
     * @param \Ptolemee\ColloqueBundle\Entity\Colloque $colloque
     * @return FieldsGroup
     */
    public function setColloque(\Ptolemee\ColloqueBundle\Entity\Colloque $colloque)
    {
        $this->colloque = $colloque;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get colloque
     *
     * @return \Ptolemee\ColloqueBundle\Entity\Colloque
     */
    public function getColloque()
    {
        return $this->colloque;
    }

}
```

And its form, FieldsGroupType :

```
class FieldsGroupType extends AbstractType
{
        /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title',      'text')
            /*->add('fields',     'collection',   array('type'        =>      new FieldType(),
                                                      'allow_add'   =>      true,
                                                      'allow_delete'   =>      true))*/
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Ptolemee\ColloqueBundle\Entity\FieldsGroup'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'ptolemee_colloquebundle_fieldsgroup';
    }
}
```

I know this should work properly without any more perist(), or anything else...
Any help would be highly appreciated, i've been working on that for hours without finding what's the right way to do....

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Just add setFieldsGroup(ArrayCollection) to your entity

```
     public function addFieldsGroup(\Ptolemee\ColloqueBundle\Entity\FieldsGroup $fieldsGroups)
        {
           $this->fieldsGroups[] = $fieldsGroups;
           $fieldsGroups->setColloque($this);
           return $this;
        }

    public function setFieldsGroup(ArrayCollection $fieldsGroups)
       {
           foreach ($fieldsGroups as $fieldsGroup) {
               $fieldsGroup->setColloque($this);
           }
           $this->fieldsGroups = $fieldsGroups;
       }
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help, but that's not working...
However, i found out that when removing $this->fieldsGroups = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection(); in my Colloque's constructor, this is working, but i don't understand why... I'm new into symfony and the lesson i've followed specified that i have to do that with a bidirectionnal relation...

Answer (score 0):

Adding setFieldsGroup(ArrayCollection) is working but it's a trick.

Simply add `, cascade={"persist"}` to your ManyToOne field

```
/**                                                                                  
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Ptolemee\ColloqueBundle\Entity\Colloque", inversedBy="fieldsGroups", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $colloque;
```

PS1 : 
Prefer handleRequest() instead of `$request->getMethod() == 'POST'` and `$form->bind($request)` if you have Symfony2.x x>=3.

PS2 : 
You can get request like this when needed (more elegant way) :

```
public function createColloqueAction(Request $request)
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help, but that's not working... 
However, i found out that when removing $this->fieldsGroups = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection(); in my Colloque's constructor, this is working, but i don't understand why... 
I'm new into symfony and the lesson i've followed specified that i have to do that with a bidirectionnal relation...
Anyway, i put this cascade={"persist"} because this is the good way to do i think.

Comment: You should let the default constructor. If it prevent the proper functioning, so you have an error elsewhere.
The rest is good, and just with adding the cascade persist is not working ?

Comment: yes, the cascade persist doesn't change anything in this case. Removing this $this->fieldsGroups = new ArrayCollection() is the action that removes the error. But i really don't know why, and i thought that this new ArrayCollection() thing was needed when using bidirectionnal relations...

Comment: Crazy, it's mean that the object is create after the form submission erasing your fieldsGroup array.
Sry, no more ideas.

Comment: no no, it doesn't mean that : when i do a Debug::dump($colloque) just before the flush, i can see that the colloque owns a FieldsGroup, so it's not erased... and doctrine tries to flush it anyway. But when i have this new ArrayCollection(), doctrine doesn't know the id of the colloque for the foreign key of the filedsGroup